# Bootstrap 4, Datetimepicker, convert to rems icon too small

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Upgrading to Bootstrap 4, and I cannot find an answer for this issue anywhere. In order to get the Datetime Picker to work, I found this version for the .CSS and JavaScript files:

https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4

This worked, my Datetime picker does what it should. However, if I then change the CSS file to use rem instead of px, the Datetime Picker's icon to the right is about half the height of what it should be. This is what the HTML looks like:

```
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 offset-2">
                 <label for="date_started">Date Started:</label>
                 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_pos_date_start" style="width: 250px;">
                    <input name="date_started" id="date_started" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                       <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </span>
                 </div> <!-- // input-group -->
                 <p class="help-block">Provide the date you started this position, if known.</p>
              </div> <!-- // col-4 -->
           </div> <!-- // row -->
```

Until I changed the site to start using rem instead of px for measurements in my CSS file, the code worked flawlessly with the correct JavaScript and so on. But what did happen is that the height of the button on the right is about half what it should be.

I realize that this code does not use the new replacement in Bootstrap 4 "input-group-append", but when I tried to change it, the whole thing stopped working. I cannot find any settings I can make to get the button to be the correct height to the right of the entryarea. If I leave it like this, it works, but the button is not the correct height.

And having made a bunch of changes to my CSS file for other parts of the site, I have no idea what may be affecting this. The whole CSS file is too long to post here, but the basics at the top are here:

```
html
{
  /* required for fixed footer */
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%; /* = 10px */
}


body
{ 
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.6rem; /* = 16px */
   /*   font-size: 16px; */
   color: #000000; 
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-top: 1.0rem; /* 10px; */
   margin-left: .2rem; /* 2px; */
   margin-right: .2rem; /* 2px; */
   padding: .5rem; /* 5px; */
   /* for fixed footer */
   margin-bottom: 4.0rem; /* 40px; */
}
```

I am hoping someone has some experience with this, or a possible solution to it. I tried putting this into my CSS file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all:

```
.input-group-addon, input-group-text
{
   height: 3.0rem !important;
   font-size: 3.0rem !important;
}
```